# Prevent window scroll below fold until button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a situation where I need the page to not be scrollable past a certain point (I have the hero set to 100vh and the user should not be able to scroll at all) and then upon click of a button the scroll prevention is disabled and the user is then automatically smooth scrolled down to an anchor link directly below (basically scroll down 100vh or the full window height). I need a smooth scrolling animation instead of just a quick jump.

I've tried playing around with variations of the following code with no luck. So far it is really buggy and jumps around and when you reload the page the body overflow is set to hidden but the window position is not always at the top of the screen so you still see some of the below the fold content but still cant scroll.

```
function() {

function smoothScroll(){ 
    windowHeight = $('window').height();
    $('html, body').stop.animate({scrollTop: windowHeight}, slow);
}

$('.bottom-nav').on('click', '.fold-trigger', function(event) {
    $('.home').css('overflow', 'visible');
    setTimeout(smoothScroll(), 1000);

});

};
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/njpatten/yxkvnymu/1/

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed Code**

```
function smoothScroll(){ 
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: windowHeight}, "slow");
}

$('.bottom-nav').on('click', '.fold-trigger', function(event) {
    $('.home').css('overflow', 'visible');
    setTimeout(smoothScroll(), 1000);

});
```

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxkvnymu/2/

**Explanation**

You are trying to get the window height by doing `$('window').height()` which is searching for a 'window' DOM element which doesn't exist. You want to use `$(window).height()` (note the omission of quotes surrounding window) because `window` is not a DOM node, it is an object.

In addition, you are using `$('html, body').stop.animate({scrollTop: windowHeight}, slow);` which has multiple errors. `.stop` is invalid because the `stop` property on the NodeList that is returned from `$('html, body')` is a function that you want to call. You should be using `$('html, body').stop()`.

Also, the `animate` portion is referencing a variable `slow`. jQuery's animate function takes `"slow"` as a string, so that line should be written as such:

```
.animate({scrollTop: windowHeight}, "slow");
```

Note the inclusion of quotes on that because we want to pass a string value of `"slow"` to jQuery's animate function, instead of a variable `slow`.

Lastly, you are surrounding all of your code in an anonymous function, which seems unnecessary.